# How to copy a location to a batch file from a file that is dragged and dropped to open the batch file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

So I've been trying to create a batch file for a piece of software called DiscEX the software requires command line use from cmd.exe windows xp or higher the way it's initiated is like this `discex (any arguments needed) location of iso file`.
Now I can get the software to run using the batch file but I can't seem to figure out how to copy the target location of a file that was dragged onto it to open the batch file up
Here is what the batch file in notepad looks like.

```
@echo off
echo Welcome to AutoDiscEx
pause
C:\windows\system32\discex 
pause
```

also I need to be able to start in the working directory of a portable hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is

```
C:\windows\system32\discex "%1"
```

to get a file path argument passed into the batch

If the batch file is in the working directory already, put

```
cd /d %~dp0 in the batch after @echo off
```

If you want to determine what drive is the external usb drive, use

```
 @echo off
 setlocal   
 set wmi='wmic logicaldisk where "volumeserialnumber='32A78F3B'" get caption'
 for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in (%wmi%) do (
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%B in ("%%A") do (set drive=%%B)
 )
 echo %drive%
```

where volumeserialnumber is the output from vol [driveletter of USB drive:] with the - removed.

Comment: actually it was "C:\windows\system32\discex %1" and thank you for the current working directory line it was super helpful

Answer (score 0):

When you drag a file on a batch file, the full file path is available in the first argument (`%1`) of the batch file. If you need this argument to be fed to the discex application as its first argument, you can do:

```
@echo off
echo Welcome to AutoDiscEx
pause

C:\windows\system32\discex %1
pause
```